# How do I stop a certain part of a program using the user's input?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that tallies grades. I want to know how to stop a certain part of a program based on the user's input. Below is the program I am working on. How do I stop the program if the user enters "done"? Also, I don't necessarily have to use "done" to exit the program. I was initially going to use -1, but I ran into a problem where I had to make a robust program where values < 0 and > 100 are not accepted.

```
   int grade;
   a=b=c=d=f=0;


   do
   {
      cout << "Enter a grade or enter done to stop. ";


      if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
          {a++;}
      if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
          {b++;}
      if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
          {c++;}
      if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
          {d++;}
      if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60)
          {f++;}



   } while (grade != 'done');
```

Comment: Ouch, that multicharacter literal is implcitly being converted to an integer to fit your type needs, but the multichar literal and single equals sign are both wrong. If you need the text possibility, you can input it as a string and convert it. I'd stick with looking for EOF, though.

Comment: Not answer to your question but a suggestion : Since all use case specified in if conditions are mutually exclusive, you should use 'else if's after the first if. This will stop the unnecessary checking of conditions once a condition satisfies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to ask user to enter **integer value**, which is **out of range of values you expected** him to enter (ex. -1). "when done - enter -1".
Also if`(grade = 'done')` - *assignement* is here, to compare use **operator==**, which is

//    if(grade == 'done')

or you can use the following approach:

```
do
   {
      cout << "Enter a grade or enter done to stop. ";
      // first try to get string from user (which he/she enters when done)
      string str;
      cin >> str;
      if (str == "done") // if done was entered - exit from the loop
         break;
      // else clear fail bit in stream object and read int value
      cin.clear();
      cin >> grade;

      if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
          {//a++;}
      if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
          {//b++;}
      if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
          {//c++;}
      if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
          {//d++;}
      if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60)
          {//f++;}

   } while (grade != 'done');
```

Comment: I was initially going to use -1 but I realized I had to make a robust program so values < 0 and > 100 are not accepted.

Comment: omg, thank you! this is a very easy way to approach this problem I have. THANKS!

Comment: @user1793565, If you say to enter -1 to stop, -1 isn't an invalid input. It's also a lot less work than reading strings and converting them to integers. However, it's even less work just going until the read fails, presumably due to EOF.

Answer (score 1):

just do a return 0? Also, you can't do grade = 'done', unless you overrode the = operator or something.

Comment: What do you mean just do return 0? I tried using sstream to convert grade to a string, but I realized it won't work for user inputted values.

Comment: @user1793565, You need double quotation marks for string literals, and you can't input strings when it's trying to read an integer, but you can do it the other way around.

Comment: If i set a,b,c,d,f to string then it's not going to tally the grades. It won't do a++, or b++ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "grade" is type int, so you can not convert int to *char, if you want that "grade" is int than you can exit with -1. Or if you want to exit with "done", than grade can be char[5], and you can use atoi() to convert string to integer to check, and strcmp() to compere "grade" with "done".

Answer (score 0):

You have write code to enter a string. You can then test if the string equals "done". If it doesn't you then convert the string to an integer, then you can check against your grade boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use numbers AND strings i suggest using stringstreams. Here is an example:

```
string Text = "456";//string containing the number
int Result;//number which will contain the result

stringstream convert(Text); // stringstream used for the conversion initialized with the  contents of Text

if ( !(convert >> Result) )//give the value to Result using the characters in the string
    Result = 0;//if that fails set Result to 0
//Result now equal to 456
```

[Source link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9645/)

Comment: I tried using the stringstream but it doesn't take inputs from users for some reason. I'm probably doing something wrong but not sure what it is

Comment: @user1793565 You could put the input from cin into a string first and then put that string into the stringstream: `cin >> Text; stringstream convert(Text);` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, single quotes denote a character literal, double quotes a null terminated string (2.14 or so).

`if(grade = 'done')` will always be true, compiler should have thrown a warning at you that you aren't doing what you think you are doing, you're assigning it then checking if it is true, which it will always be.

And you're trying to assign an integer to a string.

This seems like homework so i won't write it, but you need to take in a string from stdin, then parse it, e.g is it an integer or string, the act on that data. to terminate you can call `exit`, break from the loop or return from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the inputs as string, if the first character is not a digit then break the loop, covert the string to integer otherwise:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int grade;
    string input;
    int a, b, c, d, f;
    a=b=c=d=f=0;


    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a grade or enter done to stop: ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;
        if(!isdigit(input[0])) {
            break;
        } else {
            grade = atoi(input.c_str());
        }

        if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
          {a++;}
        if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
          {b++;}
        if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
          {c++;}
        if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
          {d++;}
        if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60)
          {f++;}


    } while (1==1);

    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;
    cout << "d = " << d << endl;
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```